# In which case does author use "for" in the following sentences?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammar

I undid the lantern cautiously(for the hinges creaked)

His room was dark (for the shutters were close fastened, through the fear of robbers)

I could see nothing of the old man's face : for i had directed the ray as if  by instinct....

Thanks for attention.

Comment: Reason adjuncts expressed with preposition phrases headed by "for" are quite formal, even archaic for some. "For" can be replaced with the more common "because", "since or "as" with no change of meaning: we understand his room was dark for/because/since/as the shutters were close-fastened ..".

Answer (score 1):

In each OP example '***for***' is being used to mean '***By reason of, on account of***'.

Used in this way '*for*' sounds, at best, poetic, at worst rather old-fashioned/stilted/affected. Much more common would be to use '***because***'.

I undid the lantern cautiously *because* the hinges creaked.

His room was dark *because* the shutters were close fastened, through the fear of robbers.

I could see nothing of the old man's face *because* I had directed the ray, as if by instinct.

Answer (score -1):

In each case, *for* is a preposition that introduces a parenthetical phrase, so it should be preceded by a comma:

> - I undid the lantern cautiously, for the hinges creaked.
> - His room was dark, for the shutters were close fastened through the fear of robbers.
> - I could see nothing of the old man's face, for I had directed the ray as if by instinct.

The important thing about parenthetical phrases is that they can be omitted without changing the meaning of the sentence.

You could enclose the parenthetical phrases in parentheses, and drop the commas, but there is no real reason to do so.

Comment: 'For' is not a preposition in any of these examples. It's the coordinator (others may dispute this classification) clause-joining usage. Contrast 'I uncovered the lantern cautiously for the miners.'